# Sudoku validator columns and cells

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that will take a users .txt file and validate the sudoku. here is an example of a file

```
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
```

So far in my code i have tried to get it t check row but it isn't checking each row. Instead it is producing this as the output.

```
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
true
```

Here is my code. Also i would like to know how i would get it to check columns and cells

```
file=input("Enter a filename: ")
fi=open(file,"r")
f=fi.read()
row=f.split("\n")
check=set(row)
print(check)
for n in check:
    seen=set(n)
    print (seen)
    if len(seen)<9:
        print ("false")
    else:
        print ("true")
```

Comment: Are you asking us to explain your code to you? My hint would be that the program is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, you just have to look closer. Note that those sets have len > 9, _including_ the empty element.

Comment: `rows = list(open(file,"r"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this enumeration technique in which I check for sub totals of 45 for rows and columns:

```
with open('data.txt') as data:

    row_total = [0 for i in range(9)]
    col_total = [0 for i in range(9)]

    for a, b in enumerate(data):

        sb_row_total = 0

        for c, d in enumerate(b.split()):

            sb_row_total += int(d)
            col_total[c] += int(d)

        row_total[a] = sb_row_total

    rows = all(i == 45 for i in row_total)
    cols = all(i == 45 for i in col_total)

    print(rows and cols)
```